# Can't activate a user on multisite install

Tags: multisite, users, user-registration

So I have a user that I can't activate with the unconfirmed plugin manually. His user was created on all appropriate sites, but his account isn't listed as activated. The link in the activation email just returns the error message: "Could not create user" even though he was created. The Unconfirmed module simply tells me "The following users could not be activated: ".*.

I looked in his user table and the key in the email matches what's in the DB, the only thing in the signups table that was odd was that he didn't have an activation time.

Any ideas on what's going on and how I can fix it?

*Edit:
There's also nothing in my apache logs indicating a php error.

Comment: What is "unconfirmed plugin" exactly there? If you are using something to extend native logic it might be better aimed at its developers/support.

Comment: Its just a plugin to easily list all unconfirmed user accounts. It has an option to manually confirm user accounts which returns the error. Though they might have some insights into what's causing the issue. WordPress is probably sending them the same vague error message of "Could not create user" though.

Comment: Since you already went to the db table, why not just change the values to be like other users that are activated. So basically manually activating it in the db. Also I think that it is not allowed for plugin support topics here.

Comment: I'm just unfamiliar with what all the activation filter/actions alter in the database to compare. Do they just alter the wp_users table and the wp_usermeta tables? The wp_registration_log? I just image there's a lot that goes on behind the scenes that I wouldn't even think of especially if any of our active plugins hook into user registration actions. This isn't a plugin support question, its a user activation question. I'll try going through core to see what logic its running to report that error.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the username in the signups table were different than the one created. I don't know if its because the user tried to register twice a few weeks apart without activating or what, but I just changed the username in the signups table to match what already existed in the wp_users table and the activation went through seemingly without a hitch.

I changed the user_login column to match the existing username.